# Javascript regex engine: Word boundaries not matching at start of string for non-word characters

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

I thought `\b` matches at the transition between word and nonword characters, or at the start or end of the string. So this should be true:

```
'#abc'.match(/\b#/)
```

But it's null, at least in Firefox and Chrome. Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\b` is equivalent to `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`. You've probably read the following from [the mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> A word boundary matches the position between a word character followed by a non-word character, or between a non-word character followed by a word character, or the beginning of the string, or the end of the string.

It isn't properly written. It should specify that it matches the beginning or end of string *when adjacent to a word character*. That's the issue with writing long sentences instead of using bullet points when trying to explain something pretty algorithmic: it's hard to read, and therefore hard to proofread.

---

Example of a correct definition from [a source other than mozilla](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the documentation I was reading. I'm building a regex with escaped search terms using MDN's `escapeRegExp`, so I can just do multiple tests like `new RegExp('\\b' + escapeRegExp(keywords), 'i')` or'd with `new RegExp('^' + escapeRegExp(keywords), 'i')` or'd with `RegExp(escapeRegExp(keywords) + '$', 'i')`. Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 0):

'`#`' is not a **Word** character, so there's no `Word` boundary to match at start of string. Simple as that.

If you delete the '`#`', so it's just `'abc'`, then '`\b`' will correctly match the `Word boundary`.

Comment: Right but then why does a `"A"` match `/\bA/` and I think it's because the empty void on both sides of the string can be considered an infinite plane of nonword characters.